# Why is adding a specific where clause to this MySQL query a performance killing bottleneck?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, optimization

Sorry for the length, wanted to give a complete description! I have a need to show a report displaying some info about an id from another table and when someone changes countries from a country and within x amount of days. Note how i can have the same country entry in the table multiple times for an id (as the info is queried at regular intervals multiple times, but they may not have moved during that time), and can also have different country entries (as they change countries).

Quick explanation of the data:
i have the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `country` (
`id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`timestamp`),
KEY `country` (`country`),
KEY `timestamp` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the entrys are like this:

```
41352   2012-03-26 15:46:01     Jamaica
41352   2012-03-05 22:49:41     Jamaican Applicant
41352   2012-02-26 15:46:01     Jamaica
41352   2012-02-16 12:11:19     Jamaica
41352   2012-02-05 23:00:30     Jamaican Applicant
```

This table has about ~214,590 total rows right now, but will have millions once the test data is replaced with real data.

What I want is some info on everyone who has left x country since y time. Here is how I would like it outputted assuming it was run on the data above:

```
id  name    last    country     TIMESTAMP   o_timestamp
41352 Sweet Mercy   Jamaica     2012-03-26 15:46:01     2012-03-05 22:49:41
41352 Sweet Mercy   Jamaica     2012-02-16 12:11:19     2012-02-05 23:00:30
```

Where o_timestamp is newer then a certain date (lets say 100), country is where they moved to, and the old country (not shown) they came from is whatever i pass into the query (Jamaican Applicant based on above data).

I developed the following query to satisfy the requirements and was using a certain id to test:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.name,
       c.last,
       a.country,
       a.timestamp,
       b.timestamp AS o_timestamp
FROM   country a
       INNER JOIN user_info c
         ON ( a.id = c.id )
       LEFT JOIN country AS b
         ON ( a.id = b.id
              AND a.timestamp != b.timestamp
              AND a.country != b.country )
WHERE  b.timestamp = (SELECT c.timestamp
                      FROM   country c
                      WHERE  a.id = c.id
                             AND a.timestamp > c.timestamp
                      ORDER  BY c.timestamp DESC
                      LIMIT  1) 
       AND a.id = 965
```

I got this to complete in ( 7 total, Query took 0.0050 sec)

and a explain extended revealed the following:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY     c   const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   const   1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY     a   ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   const   16  100.00  
1   PRIMARY     b   eq_ref  PRIMARY,timestamp   PRIMARY     11  const,func  1   100.00  Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  c   index   PRIMARY,timestamp   timestamp   8   NULL    1   700.00  Using where; Using index
```

so i figured I was pretty good and popped in this:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.name,
       c.last,
       a.country,
       a.timestamp,
       b.timestamp AS o_timestamp
FROM   country a
       INNER JOIN user_info c
         ON ( a.id = c.id )
       LEFT JOIN country AS b
         ON ( a.id = b.id
              AND a.timestamp != b.timestamp
              AND a.country != b.country )
WHERE  b.timestamp = (SELECT c.timestamp
                      FROM   country c
                      WHERE  a.id = c.id
                             AND a.timestamp > c.timestamp
                      ORDER  BY c.timestamp DESC
                      LIMIT  1) 
       AND b.country = "whatever" AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

This query took an amazing 6 minutes and 54 seconds to complete on a country that had 200 records and never completed (after going out for the afternoon and night and

coming home so a total of about 8 hours) for a country with 9000 records in the db. In real data, a country could be in there 10000 times easy. 100k would not be unreasonable.

So i do explain extended, and get this:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    filtered    Extra
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3003    100.00  
1   PRIMARY     c   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   b.id    1   100.00  
1   PRIMARY     a   ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   b.id    7   100.00  Using where
3   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  c   index   PRIMARY,timestamp   timestamp   8   NULL    1   700.00  Using where; Using index
2   DERIVED     country     range   country,timestamp   country     195     NULL    474     100.00  Using where; Using index
```

So it looks larger, but not unreasonably so.

[Removed config variables for space, let me know if needed and also the performance info since its prob a query thing.]

Let me know if i missed anything.

Comment: Why is there an ORDER BY in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @rontornambe note the `LIMIT 1` at the end. it is returning the most recent time stamp that fulfills the inner where clause

Comment: that subquery in the where clause gets me the next earliest timestamped event for that id. without the order by i could get any row that is earlier, but with order by timestamp desc limit one, i get only the one right before.

Comment: Just wondering - ORDER BY can be expensive.

Comment: Please add a detailed example to your question in the form of - given this data I would expect this result. It will make it easier to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a way to get rid of it and still get what I wanted. If there's a cheaper way to do it that would probably help unless this is a server misconfig issue.

Comment: @nnichols I added something to hopefully clarify what id like

Comment: With your sample data and the first query modified so `a.id = 41352`, do you get one or two rows output?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler 3, 1 for jamaica applicant to jamaica, 1 for jamaica back to jamaica applicant and 1 for jamaica applicant back to jamaica for the second time. I only get 2 when i search for a specific country that im leaving which would filter out leaving jamaica to go to jamaica applicant

Comment: Oh futz; you changed the data so it's all for the same id.  That adds to the confusion.  I was looking at the prior version with just 3 rows for 41352.  OK, so for each exit record from 'Jamaica Applicant' you want the next record in time that identifies a different country that they did enter.

Comment: yeah, sorry I added it to clarify a point nnichols had. I removed other ids to make the example simplier, but if i had 3 ids that were switching I would expect them all to show up in the results based on the criteria mentioned in the above comment. I can add some more to help clarify if needed

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah, basically on some conditions in the exit record (date and country they were in) I want to show the new entry values and some generic info about that nation (which is a simple join for me and can be extracted out of this question to focus on the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't adding a criterion; it is dropping one that's doing the damage.  In the original query, you had:

```
AND a.id = 965
```

This means that the query execution does not need to read the entire `a` (`country`) table.  In your second, performance-killed query, you change that criterion to:

```
AND b.country = "whatever"
AND timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You no longer have a really restrictive criterion on `a`, so things work much more slowly.

Things get more complex when it is realized that `b` is another reference to `country`.  Nevertheless, the change from a condition on `a` to `b` (where `b` is on the outer side of an outer join) is not trivial; it takes a lot longer to deal with the query conditions.

---

> Does that mean because I'm not looking for a specific id, I'm out of luck?

With the given query structure, the answer seems to be 'yes', but the given query structure may be, shall we say, sub-optimal.

Your 'fast enough when working on one ID' query is:

```
SELECT a.id,
       c.name,
       c.last,
       a.country,
       a.timestamp,
       b.timestamp AS o_timestamp
FROM   country a
       INNER JOIN user_info c
         ON ( a.id = c.id )
       LEFT JOIN country AS b
         ON ( a.id = b.id
              AND a.timestamp != b.timestamp
              AND a.country != b.country )
WHERE  b.timestamp = (SELECT c.timestamp
                      FROM   country c
                      WHERE  a.id = c.id
                             AND a.timestamp > c.timestamp
                      ORDER  BY c.timestamp DESC
                      LIMIT  1) 
       AND a.id = 965
```

I don't fully understand this query and what it is attempting to do.  You need to be aware that outer joins are more expensive than inner joins, and conditions on the outer-joined table like

```
b.timestamp = (...correlated sub-query...)
```

are fiendishly expensive.  One problem is that there might be a NULL in the `b` columns including `timestamp`, but the sub-query is wasted on that because the condition won't be satisfied unless the values are non-null, so we end up wondering 'why an OUTER join'?

When you added the revised condition, you should have received an 'ambiguous column name' error since that time stamp could be from `a` or `c`.  Also, the `b.country = "whatever"` condition is another that only makes sense when the `b` values are not null, so again, the OUTER join is dubious.

As I understand it, the `country` table contains records about who entered which country and when.  Also, FWIW, I'm tolerably certain that the join with the `user_info` table is a negligible performance issue; the problem is all down to the three references to the `country` table.

---

Judging from some of the clarifications, you could build up the query incrementally, maybe something like this.

1. Find each pair of country records for the same `id` where the records are adjacent in time sequence, and the older of the pair is for a given country ('Jamaica Applicant') and the newer is for a different country.

   The easy part of this is:

   ```
   SELECT a.id, a.country, a.timestamp, b.country, b.timestamp
     FROM country AS a
     JOIN country AS b
       ON a.id = b.id
      AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp
      AND a.country = 'Jamaica Applicant'
      AND b.country != a.country
   ```

   This does most of the job, but does not ensure adjacency for the entries.  To do that, we have to insist there there is not record in `country` table for the same `id`  in between (but not including) the two timestamps, `a.timestamp` and `b.timestamp`.  That's an extra NOT EXISTS condition:

   ```
   SELECT a.id,
          a.country   AS o_country,
          a.timestamp AS o_timestamp,
          b.country   AS n_country,
          b.timestamp AS n_timestamp
     FROM country AS a
     JOIN country AS b
       ON a.id = b.id
      AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp
      AND a.country = 'Jamaica Applicant'
      AND b.country != a.country
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
          (SELECT *
             FROM country AS c
            WHERE c.timestamp > a.timestamp
              AND c.timestamp < b.timestamp
              AND c.id = a.id
          )
   ```

   Note that BETWEEN AND notation is not suitable.  It includes the end points in the range, but we explicitly need the end points excluded.
2. Given the list of country entries above, we now need to select just those rows where the ... hmmm, well, what is the criterion?  I think you get to choose, but the result can be joined with the `user_info` table easily:

   ```
   SELECT e.id, u.name, u.last, e.o_country, e.o_timestamp, e.n_country, e_n_timestamp
     FROM (SELECT a.id,
                  a.country   AS o_country,
                  a.timestamp AS o_timestamp,
                  b.country   AS n_country,
                  b.timestamp AS n_timestamp
             FROM country AS a
             JOIN country AS b
               ON a.id = b.id
              AND b.timestamp > a.timestamp
              AND a.country = 'Jamaica Applicant'
              AND b.country != a.country
            WHERE NOT EXISTS
                  (SELECT *
                     FROM country AS c
                    WHERE c.timestamp > a.timestamp
                      AND c.timestamp < b.timestamp
                      AND c.id = a.id
                  )
          ) AS e
     JOIN user_info AS u ON e.id = u.id
    WHERE e.o_timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
   ```

I'm not about to guarantee that the performance will be better (or even that it is syntactically correct; it hasn't been past an SQL DBMS).  But I think the complex query structure for getting the adjacent dates is neater and probably better performing than the original code.  Note, in particular, that it does not use any outer join, (explicit) ordering or limit clauses.  That should help.

Comment: That makes sense, and would be supported by the fact that when i removed id and country and timestamp I saw no real reduction in time for the query to run. Does that mean because im not looking for a specific id im out of luck?

Comment: sorry for the delay. After lots of testing, this is 1000% times better. It still hangs up in a few cases that i'm not entirely sure about. I think one of the subqueries might return a ton of results in certain cases, and that would slow it down. Thanks

Comment: Figured out that the reason for the slow down now is the fact that AWS throttles micro instances to 1% cpu if they do any intensive work. This led to any query going over a certain amount of work to pretty much never finish. I tried your query again on a small instance and it completed on 4.5 million rows selecting a country with 800,000 entries in 40 seconds.

Comment: That's quite a bit better performance than you had beforehand.  Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You should check this reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

What it says, is that NOW() function could return a string (depending on the context), and date_add could return a string (depending on the parameters). My guess is, you're getting strings, and then only casting to dates on the comparison (which happens on every record). Can you try AND timestamp > cast(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) as datetime), that might improve the performance.

Comment: this doesnt seem to help much, since even if i take it out I get similar performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not proposing this as a finished solution but it is a start that I shall return to. Please let me know how this performs against your test dataset -

```
SELECT ui.*, c1.*, MAX(c2.timestamp)
FROM country c1
INNER JOIN user_info ui
    ON c1.id = ui.id
INNER JOIN country c2
    ON c1.id = c2.id
    AND c1.timestamp > c2.timestamp
    AND c1.country <> c2.country
WHERE c2.timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND c2.country = 'somewhere'
GROUP BY c1.id
```

The next step is to add a LEFT JOIN to make sure there are no other records in between -

```
SELECT ui.*, c1.*, c2.timestamp
FROM country c1
INNER JOIN user_info ui
    ON c1.id = ui.id
INNER JOIN country c2
    ON c1.id = c2.id
    AND c1.timestamp > c2.timestamp
    AND c1.country <> c2.country

LEFT JOIN country c3
    ON c1.id = c3.id
    AND c1.timetsamp > c3.timestamp
    AND c2.timestamp < c2.timetsamp

WHERE c2.timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND c2.country = 'somewhere'
AND c3.id IS NULL
```

Comment: I ran it and its fast at least :)

Comment: problems i see:
only 1 per id (someone can leave a country many times), showing only the first time they were seen in the old country and only the last time they were in the old country. Ill elaborate more in OP.

Comment: i enhanced the example to show how i expect multiples of the same nation id and the timestamps i expect for them. I might be ok with not requiring the same id to show up each time hes left the country more then once. The latest would be fine then, assuming this would make the query faster.